# Stackoverflow questions not displaying in chronological order in Chromium webbrowser

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, stack-overflow

When I use Chromium webbrowser to view Stackoverflow the questions in the 'interesting' section do not display in chronological order. In every other browser I tried (IE, Opera, FF, Chrome) the question will display with the latest posted questions above. In Chromium webbrowser the questions will display in a random order with sometimes questions of 3hours old.

I have not changed anything as far as I know. (if it even is possible to change that) 
So my question is why does it do this only in Chromium webbrowser and is there anything I can do to change it?

EDIT:

As you can see here the question are in random order.

[image]

Comment: How are you ordering them? There are additional tabs to sort these lists, so it is possible that Chromium saved a different sort order. By the way - what do you mean by "interesting" section? Where is that?

Comment: Any chance of a screenshot to help identify the cause?

Comment: @JonW, screenshot incoming! and Oded, I am not ordering anything, it basicly is the Stackoverflow homepage.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We are currently trialing an alternative sort order on this page, to show what our algorithm came up with as questions you would find more interesting than simply showing a list in chronological order.

Whether you will be part of the sample or not is random, but also depends on the browser you are using.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I have another question about this. Is there any way to get the normal sort order back? I personaly prefer the old sort order so I would like to use that. If there is no way to get the old sort order back then I would like to know how long it will take till the trial will be over and you will use this sort order for everyone or keep using the old order.

Comment: @Daanvn - I don't believe we have a way to opt-out of our A/B testing at this time, sorry. When the experiment is over, things would either go back to how they were before, or everyone will see the change.

Comment: Allright, then I will just try to adapt to this and I'll see what happens when the experiment is over. Thanks again for the response!