# Can we see some of the AB testing results that StackExchange run?

Tags: feature-request, testing

Following on from this question: [Stackoverflow questions not displaying in chronological order in Chromium webbrowser](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/175289/stackoverflow-questions-not-displaying-in-chronological-order-in-chromium-webbro)

it would be interesting to see what some of the other AB tests that Stack Exchange have run, what they involved, what the findings were, and whether any changes to the site(s) were made as a result of this.

Possibly some SE blog posts or something, but it'd be very interesting to see how these tests influence the direction Stack Exchange takes for some decisions.

There are precious few sites out there that share their results (well, there are places like: http://whichtestwon.com/) so it would be great to be able to show other people that AB testing is a good thing to do.

Comment: Yes please! This would be pretty cool. Like the Summer of Love tests but actually interesting and useful for something other than info porn.